# Need to test Speakatoo API on Postman

Tags: text-to-speech

I am looking to test my Speakatoo API credentials for my Text to Speech setup in my CRM. I have referred the [API documentation](https://www.speakatoo.com/documentation_view/speakatoo--api-documentation) however, I am not getting the JSON response as expected.

Can someone guide me how can I first setup the test on postman and then implement for my PHP application.

I tried to include the raw request as below:

```
{
  "username":"cyro***@gmail.com",
  "password":"*********",
  "tts_title":"testing_API",
  "ssml_mode":"0",
  "tts_engine":"neural",
  "tts_format":"3gp",
  "tts_text":"Text for synthesize",
  "tts_resource_ids":"TRDu7S1e63c6f288f85180a9130c4e5e10f39dc7fsmJ1XYfxH",
  "synthesize_type":"save"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you should take the raw JSON body and test with your credentials. Don't forget to pass header Authorization else it won't work.

You may also implement in your application and it should work. Additionally, you can always contact their support team.